# Add item to list in python script on other server

Tags: python, list, networking

How can I run a python script on server A that can add entries to a list-item in another python script on server B? (Needs to be hyperefficient.)

Are there any easy solutions (or modules) that help with this?

Thanks

Comment: `multiprocessing` supports communications with remote machines.  You could also set up a REST interface or something similar on server B.

Comment: or http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use xmlrpclib to call functions remotely. 
Make a function that appends values to a global array, then register the function with xmlrpclib and call it from machine B.

It's pretty easy to use.  Here is a good starting point: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#boolean-objects

Made an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import xmlrpclib

arrayToAppend = []

def appendArray(value):
    global arrayToAppend
    arrayToAppend.append(value)
    return 1

def valueOfArray():
    return arrayToAppend

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))
print "Listening on port 8000..."
server.register_function(appendArray, "appendArray")
server.register_function(valueOfArray, "valueOfArray")
server.serve_forever()
```

Then test/use it like so

```
>>> import xmlrpclib
>>> p = xmlrpclib.Server("http://localhost:8000")
>>> p.appendArray("test1")
1
>>> p.valueOfArray()
['test1']
>>> p.appendArray("test2")
1
>>> p.valueOfArray()
['test1','test2']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, seems simple enough. At 500 entries per second, any performance issues with xmlrpclib?  Was also considering a Tornado httpserver, but perhaps that's just ridiculous? ;) Thanks for input.

Comment: Would the client side code be blocking, btw? How can I do it asynchronously?

Comment: I've never hammered it that hard.  Not sure how it would perform.  I would certainly be interested in the results if you would be so kind as to post what you find back.  As for asynchronously, if I understand the goal, I would look into a multi-threaded queuing mechanism for the client side.  http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html is thread safe, so I would start there.

Comment: Well, preliminary testing of your example shows a 25% CPU consumption for 100 strings (each 2500bytes) per second on a small AWS instance and over local network. Rather horrible performance, in other words. =(